# Migrate Jenkins jobs from Cloud Bees to another Jenkins server

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, cloudbees, jenkins-cli

I have a Jenkins server at CloudBees server and it has a lot of jobs.
I have created new Jenkins server at AWS Ec2 instance. 
Now, I need to migrate all Jenkins jobs from CloudBees to New Jenkins Server(AWS EC2instance)

How can I do this task? Is there any way to migrate all jobs by CLI?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Backup Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Backup+Plugin) or [thinBackup](https://devopscube.com/jenkins-backup-data-configurations/)

Answer (score 0):

You first need to ensure that you do not use proprietary CloudBees features (RBAC, Folders+ plugins). This is the only thing that's really specific to migrating from a CloudBees Jenkins.

After that, standard steps for migrating Jenkins apply:

- ensure that you have same plugins installed on the new Jenkins
- align credentials and credentials-IDS
- API tokens need special handling

After that, you can just copy all `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/*/config.xml` files (if using folders, copy recursively).

You can also copy job configs via CLI or REST API, but usually the fastest way is to copy directly on filesystem level.